# Cannot do populate() with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema, ref, mongoose-populate

I am new to MongoDB and Mongoose and I want to perform a populate() between two documents. After consulting the documentation and searching for answers, I am turning to you for help.
I have two models:

**Note model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const noteSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    title: { 
        type: String, 
        required: true 
    },
    color: { 
        type: String, 
        required: true 
    },
    position: { 
        type: Number, 
        required: true 
    },
    isCheckBoxMode: { 
        type: Boolean,
        required: true 
    },
    items: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Item'
    }]
}, {timestamps: true });

const Note = mongoose.model('Note', noteSchema);

module.exports = Note;
```

**Item Model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const itemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    text: {
        type: String, 
        required: true
    },
    isCompleted: {
        type: Boolean, 
        required: true
    },
    noteId: { 
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Note',
        required: true
    },
}, {timestamps: true });

const Item = mongoose.model('Item', itemSchema);

module.exports = Item;
```

In this query, I would like to retrieve an array of all the items linked to the noteId, using the "items" property, which refers to the Item document. As you can see above, I have made sure to reference between the two documents, on one hand with the items property and its ref Item, and on the other hand with the NoteId property whose id corresponds to the correct note and refers to the Note document.

It's better to have an example. I am using Mongo Atlas to quickly deploy a database. I created a note with Postman whose id is "6553448ef2c06064f266f785":

[Note document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUW6k.png)

and two items each referring to noteId "6553448ef2c06064f266f785":

[Item document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPWcf.png)

Unfortunately, when I send my request with populate('items') to retrieve the content of my items, I receive an empty array:

```
router.get('/:noteId', (req, res, next) => {
    const id = req.params.noteId;
    Note.findById(id)
        .populate('items')
        .exec()
        .then(doc => {
            if (doc) {
                res.status(200).json({
                    notes: doc,
                });
            }else {
                res.status(404).json({message : 'No Valid entry found for provided ID'});
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({error: err});
        });
});
```

The request and response in Postman

[request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYwsh.png)

I found another solution, using "virtuals", but it is not the most optimized solution and I am afraid of losing performance.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const noteSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    title: { 
        type: String, 
        required: true 
    },
    color: { 
        type: String, 
        required: true 
    },
    position: { 
        type: Number, 
        required: true 
    },
    isCheckBoxMode: { 
        type: Boolean,
        required: true 
    },
}, {timestamps: true });

noteSchema.virtual('items', {
    ref: 'Item',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'noteId'
});

noteSchema.set('toObject', { virtuals: true });
noteSchema.set('toJSON', { virtuals: true });

const Note = mongoose.model('Note', noteSchema);

module.exports = Note;
```

Sorry if my question is a bit stupid, but I searched for a long time and couldn't find any solutions. thank you in advance for your help

I tried to link the two documents following the Mongoose documentation as well as other Stack Overflow posts, but it didn't work. Also, I set up a 'virtual' which worked and allows me to retrieve all the items, but this is not optimized. Also, when I add item with a POST route, if in my request I also add the item's id to the 'items' array of the note, the populate works.
But this is also not an optimized solution. I would like to do a simple populate between two 'refs'.

Comment: If you turn on [debugging](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html#enable_debugging) you can see the queries Mongoose generates. It can be helpful to include these in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your Note schema looks fine. You have an `items` property that has been correctly defined as an array of `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` with the corresponding `ref:'Note'` so that looks textbook.

My advice would be to explicitly pass the `path` and `model` properties to the `populate` method and adopt `async/await` pattern like so:

```js
router.get('/:noteId', async (req, res, next) => { //< Mark as async
   try{
      const id = req.params.noteId;
      const doc = await Note.findById(id).populate({ //< use await 
         path: 'items', model: Item //< pass in the path and model
      });
      if(!doc){
         return res.status(400).json({
            message : 'No Valid entry found for provided ID'
         });
      }else{
         return res.status(200).json({
            notes: doc,
         });
      } 
   }catch(err){
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({error: err});
   }
});
```

**Note**: please ensure that there are `ObjectId` values in the `items` array. It is not clear from your compass screenshot because the `items` array is collapsed in the display. Lastly, your instrincts are correct and you don't need virtuals for this.

Comment: Ty for your reply :)
It's a great idea, but unfortunately, it doesn't work. I still get an empty array despite using the `async/await` approach and explicitly passing the `path` and `model` properties. I recreated a `note` and `items` to be sure.

However, indeed, in response to your *Note*, I don't have `objectIds` in the items of my array. Every time I create an item, do I need to make another request on the Note to push the item's id into the note? 
I thought Mongoose would automatically search in the Item document for noteIds that correspond to the note. Sorry, I'm not used to NoSQL.

Comment: Yes you would need to add the item id into the Notes.items array whenever you create a new item. This is not done automatically for you unfortunately.

Comment: I thought mongoose was magic. Everything clears up thank you very much

Comment: I think a [post hook](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#post-async) would be of benefit to you. Having a post `save` hook on the Item schema that pushes the id into the Notes.items array would work in your case. That's the magic part!

Comment: thank you very much, this tip is very useful